# Python + lxml/xpath - возникают дубли при парсинге

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

Есть страница http://vkino.com.ua/cinema/kinoodessa-kinostancia/showtimes/#!=&cinema-section=%2Fshowtimes%2F

При парсинге в последнем цикле возникает дублирование времени и ссылок.

```
import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring

def prepare(url):
    url = requests.get(url)
    tree = fromstring(url.text)
    tree.make_links_absolute(url.url)
    return tree

def detailed_cinemas_films(url):
    showtimes_tab_url = '/showtimes/#!=&cinema-section=%2Fshowtimes%2F'
    tree = prepare(url + showtimes_tab_url)
    for film in tree.xpath('//div[@class="content"]'):
        film_name = film.xpath('.//a[@class="navi"]/text()')[0]
        for dates in film.xpath('.//li[contains(@class,"showtimes-day sdt")]'):
            film_dates = dates.xpath('.//div[@class="date"]/text()')

            #В этом цикле возникает дублирование времени и ссылок
            for times in film.xpath('.//ul[@class="showtimes-day-block"]/li/a'):
                film_times = times.xpath('text()')
                film_booking_url = times.xpath('@href')
                print(film_name, film_dates, film_times, film_booking_url)

detailed_cinemas_films('http://vkino.com.ua/cinema/kinoodessa-kinostancia')
```

Подскажите, где косяк?

Comment: Вопрос не понятно что точно нужно какой вывод?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Невнимательность моя виновата.
Нужно строку

```
for times in film.xpath('.//ul[@class="showtimes-day-block"]/li/a'):
```

поменять было на

```
for times in dates.xpath('.//ul[@class="showtimes-day-block"]/li//a'):
```

film.xpath поменял на dates.xpath. Из-за этого неправильно формировался цикл.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы получить все `href`, который вложен в `li` можно использовать:

```
xpath('//li/a')
```

Answer (score 0):

можно такой xpath

```
//li/a/@href
```